# End program after number of inputs

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, increment

What my program does? Take input from user, it needs to be between 0-99.
Program ends when user guesses the number "guess" which is 45 or after taking 10 tries.
The problem is that I cant figure out the second part of this game.

```
guess = 45

game = do
putStrLn ("Give a number between 0 and 99")
a <- getLine
let x = read a
if x == guess then print ("You got it!") else game
```

Comment: Make a helper function where you use a parameter for the number of guesses and you call this recursively with a decremented value.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a helper function where you use a parameter with the number of guesses. Each time you make a recursive call where you decrement the number of guesses, if the variable is less than or equal to zero, we can stop the recursion:

```
guess :: Int
guess = 45

tries :: Int
tries = 10

main :: IO ()
main = game tries

game :: Int -> IO ()
game n
  | n <= 0 = putStrLn "end of the game"
  | otherwise = do
      putStrLn "Give a number between 0 and 99"
      a <- readLn
      if a == guess then putStrLn "You got it!" else game (n-1)
```

Comment: I got two errors - first is "multiple declaration of main", second is "variable a not in scope:

Comment: @dronikk: your program defines another `main`.

Comment: its actually only program i got in my .hs file

Comment: @dronikk: but you already got another program running before making the modifications, so you defined a `main` somewhere.

Comment: I even tried to change name of it but its still the same. Thats how it looks with error: 
https://i.imgur.com/zTPFZGP.png

Comment: @dronikk: the first one should be the signature, so there first `main` line had a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Willem! Had to rearrange some things in the code but you gave me the idea. Thats how now it looks like:

```
guess = 45
tries = 10

main = zad5 tries

zad5 y = do
putStrLn ("Give a number between 0 and 99")
a <- getLine
let x = read a
if y==1 || x == guess then print ("end of the game") else zad5 (y-1)
```